# Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "null". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase, angularfire

I've followed Packt Publishing to create a simple projects portfolio and I am currently getting:

Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

on the **projects.tpl.html** page, it displays project along with keywords, the title links to the individual project.

```
<a href="#/projects/{{id}}">{{project.title}}</a>
```

[image]

it goes to a page showing the title and keywords

[image]

however, when you refresh the page, it goes back to
[image]
and throws this error
[image]

---

**projects.svc.js**

```
'use strict';

app.factory("projectSvc", ['FIREBASE_URI', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject',
  function(FIREBASE_URI, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
var projectsUri = FIREBASE_URI + '/projects';
var projectsRef = new Firebase(projectsUri);
var projects = $firebaseArray(projectsRef);

var getProjects = function () {
  return projects;
};

var getProject = function (index) {
  var key = projects.$keyAt(index);
  var projectRef = projectsRef.child(key);
  return $firebaseObject(projectRef);
};

return {
  getProjects: getProjects,
  getProject: getProject
}
  }]);
```

project.ctrl.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('ProjectCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'projectSvc',
function ($scope, $routeParams, projectSvc) {

var hasAnError = false;

$scope.hasError = function () {
  return hasAnError;
};

if ($routeParams.projectIndex !== null) {
  var index = parseInt($routeParams.projectIndex);

  if (!isNaN(index)) {
    projectSvc.getProject(index).$bindTo($scope, "project");
  }
  else {
    hasAnError = true;
  }
}
}
]);
```

Any ideas on what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. ParseInt needs a second parameter, radix. In some circumstances it may be 8 not 10. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
2. var key = projects.$keyAt(index);
   var projectRef = projectsRef.child(key); exception is caused by these lines. May be these operations are async and you do not get right value for key. You may access uninitialized object. Try to put all code into $loaded callback. See here https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html